# Pandas how to 'pythonically' reform dataframe so that index is key and dates are columns

Tags: python, pandas

Take a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1',
                           '1'],
                   'Dt': ['2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03'],
                   'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

and convert to dataframe that looks like the following

| Key | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-02 | 2021-08-03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I can see how to manually do this in a loop but is there a quicker more 'pythonic' way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.pivot(*df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Dt   2021-08-01  2021-08-02  2021-08-03
Key                                    
0             1           2           3
1             4           5           6
```

Alternative `set_index & unstack` option -

```
df.set_index(['Key', 'Dt']).unstack()
```

Comment: Please avoid the `*df` "trick", it only works if there are 3 columns in the correct order, it is not generalizable nor good practice